# How to choose database table to update druing runtime

Tags: c#, sql, database, runtime, builder

I am trying to update different tables in my db depending on which object a FactoryBuilder returns in my code. 
I want to use the InstrumentFactory which gives me the object/Instrument at runtime which I then do some operations with (updating info)

```
var tmpInstrument = InstrumentFactory.MakeInstrument(nameOfTable);
//old code was.....  var tmpInstrument = new SuperTable();
```

However, when I later want to update my DB I don't know how to code it as the object by the InstrumentFactory is set at runtime depening on "nameOfTable". I want to update different tables depending on what object tmpInstrument might be.

```
                    if (tmpInstrument is SuperTable)
                    {
                       _context.SupterTable.Add((ObjectCast)tmpInstrument);

                       _context.SaveChanges();

                    }
```

**Is there any nice way to say update _context.ThisParticularTable or _context.AnotherObjectTable depending on which object the tmpSplitInfo is 
And also removing the if-statement and casting.**

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I was looking for (thanks Elias).

```
_context.Set(tmpInstrument.GetType()).Add(tmpInstrument);
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're trying to determine whether `tmpSplitInfo` is of type `SuperTable` here, so I suggest you check out the [`is` keyword](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/is):

```
if(tmpSplitinfo is SuperTable)
{
   _context.SuperTable.Add(tmpInstrument);
   _context.SaveChanges();
}
```

Comment: That's solves the firstproblem. 

When it comes to updating the database it seems that it can't be done without casting, 

    _context.SuperTable.Add((SuperTable)tmpInstrument);

Would there be any way to avoid the casting?

Comment: @Johan Maybe - a more complete code sample might help. I'm not exactly sure what the relationship between tmpSplitInfo and tmpInstrument is intended to be, here. If you're just trying to dodge this particular casting syntax, you might be able to make use of the ["is 'Type pattern'"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/is#type-pattern) to take advantage of something like `if(tmpInstrument is SuperTable ti)`

Comment: You're right cmhoequist, there were some typos, tmpSplitInto is supposed to be tmpInstrument. 
I received some input yesterday and have now used: 

 _context.Set(tmpInstrument.GetType()).Add(tmpInstrument);